# a simple d3 graph can't be load in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I'm learning to build D3 graph in a rails application. but somehow i can't load the graph.
So basically, what i did is download the d3.zip from d3 github. put d3.js and d3.min.js in assets/javascript/ and require them both in the application.js.

Here is the d3 code in my view,

```
<% content_for(:inline_javascript) do %> 
      <script> 
        var w = 200,
        h = 200,
        p = 10;

        var data = [{count:100,year:1999},
            {count:240,year:2010},
            {count:290,year:2009}];

        var bar_height = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.count; }) )  // min max of count
            .range([p,h-p]);  // min max of area to plot in


        var bar_xpos = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }) )  // min max of year
            .range([p,w-p]);  // min max of area to plot in


        var svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

        svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return bar_xpos(d.year); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { 
                return h - bar_height(d.count); })
            .attr("width", 10)
            .attr("height", function(d) {return bar_height(d.count); })
            .attr("fill", "steelblue")
      </script>
    <%end%>
```

but the page show nothing. and there's no errors when i inspect elements on the browser. So i wonder if anyone can tell me what is wrong with what i did?

Thanks!

Edit:

so finally i found out in rails, i need to have a placeholder for the d3 graph, and so it needs a id to identify the graph. The idea is like that. but i only need to add line,

```
 <svg class="chart"></svg>
```

The graph shows on the page!

Comment: You only need d3.min.js. No need of putting d3.js.

Comment: @ram Thanks! i deleted d3.js.. but still no graph showing....

Comment: Could you try this? Add this line console.log(d3.version); before var w = 200... and let me konw its result in browser console(press F12).

Comment: @ram hmm i added console.log(d3.version); . there's nothing in browser console except this warning "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. " not sure if it is relevant. but i downloaded the latest version 3.4.4 in github. is that what you want to know?

Comment: @ram my bad, i added in a wrong page. the result is the same. 3.4.4

Comment: @user2775888 Do you have an `svg` element on this page?

Comment: @ilyai, no i didn't. i just realized last night. adding <svg class="chart"></svg> is helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3's approach is somewhat similar to jQuery. It will not do anything unless you explicitly ask it to.

To do any visualization first it is required to select the node(s) to operate on.
D3 provides [select](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_select) and [selectAll](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_selectAll) methods for this.

And If no elements in the current document match the specified selector, they return the empty selection, hence no errors will be shown.